# p-values not showing up

Tags: python, python-3.x, regression

Seeking your kind advice please. Im trying to do backward elimination to figure the best indicators of revenue and share price, from the cash flow statement. Here is an excerpt of the csv data source:
[image: keystats-ecom2018.csv]

```
    import numpy as np  
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
    import pandas as pd 

    dataset = pd.read_csv('keystats-ecom2018.csv')  
    X = dataset.iloc[:, :-3].values  
    y = dataset.iloc[:, 16].values  

    import statsmodels.formula.api as sm  
    X = np.append(arr = np.ones((9, 1)).astype(int), values = X, axis = 1)  
    X_opt = X[:, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]  
    regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog=y, exog=X_opt).fit()  
    regressor_OLS.summary()`
```

Seeking clarification please as to why P > |t| is not showing any value that I can use to do backward elimination in the results below? Thanks so much!

***results***

[image: results - p-value all showing 'nan']

Comment: Do you have only 1 observation per coefficient?

Comment: Hello! I have 9 observations per coefficient :)

Comment: @Lynn You'll increase your chances of getting a useful answer dramatically by providing a sample dataset.